# printing the encrypted text twice and not encrypting first letter of each sentence

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

can someone locate the problem in my code. I am trying to write a caesar cipher encryption code for a text file using buffer reader. The text file is all lower case and contains some punctuations as well. When i output my file its printing the encrypted code twice and not shifting the first letter of each sentence at all. Here is my block of code:

```
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
{
    for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
    {
        char enchar;
        char chr= line.charAt(i);
        if(chr >='a' && chr<='z')
        {
            enchar=(char)((chr -'a'+ keyvalue ) % 26 + 'a');
        }
        else
            enchar=chr;
        output+=String.valueOf(enchar);
    }
    bufferedWriter.write(output);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
}
```

Comment: How does the keyvalue get it's value from?

Comment: Through a nextInt() method passed as:int keyvalue= input.nextInt();

Comment: hey is someone here to help me out

Comment: can you post sample input and what output you are getting?

Comment: the input text file is something like this WITH SHIFT OF 2:They push the human race forward. And while some may see them as the crazy ones, we see genius. .
aND HERE IS THE OUTPUT:Tjga rwuj vjg jwocp tceg hqtyctf. Apf yjkng uqog oca ugg vjgo cu vjg etcba qpgu, yg ugg igpkwu.Tjga rwuj vjg jwocp tceg hqtyctf. Apf yjkng uqog oca ugg vjgo cu vjg etcba qpgu, yg ugg igpkwu.

Comment: Use a debugger. Look at how output is being added to. What you are describing sounds like the first character is not being encoded. Not to mention your else clause will be visited when the character is uppercase. Your code depends on ASCII ordering, and only cares about lowercase chars.

Comment: to clarify my text file is only lower case and some punctuations. i will try to look into the debugger thing and see ...

Comment: Well i included a condition for uppercase as well.Thanks for pointing that one....but anyways i will solve the repetition problem later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
  bufferedWriter.write(output);
  bufferedWriter.newLine();
  bufferedWriter.flush();
}
bufferedWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said repeatedly that your plaintext file contains only lowercase letters, but it doesn't. The first letter of every sentence is clearly an uppercase letter as seen in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113416/printing-the-encrypted-text-twice-and-not-encrypting-first-letter-of-each-senten#comment54043150_33113416).

If you want to handle Upper case letters too, then just add another clause:

```
char enchar;
char chr= line.charAt(i);
if(chr >='a' && chr<='z')
{
    enchar=(char)((chr -'a'+ keyvalue ) % 26 + 'a');
}
else if(chr >='A' && chr<='Z')
{
    enchar=(char)((chr -'A'+ keyvalue ) % 26 + 'A');
}
else
    enchar=chr;
output+=String.valueOf(enchar);
```

Now, the double printing happens because you're continuously appending the ciphertext characters to `output`, but also write `output` to the Writer after every line. You need to start with a fresh `output` for each line:

```
while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
{
    output = ""; // <---- THIS
    for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
    {
        ...
        output+=String.valueOf(enchar);
    }
    bufferedWriter.write(output);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
}
```

Comment: You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) answers that solve your issue. Please check if there are answers to your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5415955/s-taj?tab=questions) that solve your issue. If they do, please accept them.